# Plot multivariate Gaussian contours with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to augment a plot with contours from a 2D Gaussian distribution with known mean and covariance. Ideally I would just have to specify the function and it would be plotted in 2D (like `stat_function` except for 2 dimensions). I can do it with `geom_raster` by generating a grid of probabilites. Can I use `geom_contour2d` somehow instead?

```
m <- c(.5, -.5)
sigma <- matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1), nrow=2)
data.grid <- expand.grid(s.1 = seq(-3, 3, length.out=200), s.2 = seq(-3, 3, length.out=200))
q.samp <- cbind(data.grid, prob = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(data.grid, mean = m, sigma = sigma))
ggplot(q.samp, aes(x=s.1, y=s.2)) + 
    geom_raster(aes(fill = prob)) +
    coord_fixed(xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3), ratio = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `ellipse` package to construct the contour data directly. This still requires a separate call to construct the data, but is much more efficient (in both space and time) than your solution of constructing an entire grid and then finding the contours.

```
library(ellipse)
library(plyr)  ## not necessary, but convenient
m <- c(.5, -.5)
sigma <- matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1), nrow=2)
alpha_levels <- seq(0.5,0.95,by=0.05) ## or whatever you want
names(alpha_levels) <- alpha_levels ## to get id column in result
contour_data <- ldply(alpha_levels,ellipse,x=sigma,
      scale=c(1,1),  ## needed for positional matching
      centre=m)
```

(you could use `lapply` and `rbind` from base R; `plyr::ldply` is just a shortcut)

Now plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(contour_data,aes(x,y,group=.id))+geom_path()
```

Answer (score 8):

I was barking up the wrong tree looking at `2d` stuff. You can achieve what I want with `geom_contour` and by adding a `z` aesthetic:

```
m <- c(.5, -.5)
sigma <- matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1), nrow=2)
data.grid <- expand.grid(s.1 = seq(-3, 3, length.out=200), s.2 = seq(-3, 3, length.out=200))
q.samp <- cbind(data.grid, prob = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(data.grid, mean = m, sigma = sigma))
ggplot(q.samp, aes(x=s.1, y=s.2, z=prob)) + 
    geom_contour() +
    coord_fixed(xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3), ratio = 1)
```

[image]